# WF 4 - get list of status of workflows without Appfabric

Tags: workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4

Is it possible to get status of workflows that are not hosted on appfabric.
I would like to know any workflows that are suspended, completed and error.

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a persistance database , you can get the status of the instance by querying Instances database. Otherwise you can get the status by querying workflowInstance tracking table.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use the same approach as AppFabric. Create a TrackingParticipant and st0re the info somewhere like in a database where you can query it. The is a Microsoft sample that will use SQL Server to do just that.

Comment: Thanks a lot, +1 for the info ... I just needed something simpler. Thanks again